# Related rates Calculus

Tags: calculus

At what rate is water being poured into a cylindrical glass of diameter 10cm if the depth of the water is increasing at a rate of 0.4cm/s?

I am totally lost and I don't know what formula to use.

Could someone help me? Thank you.

Comment: Write down the formula for the volume of a cylinder.

Comment: You "don't know what formula to use". When in doubt, think about the problem. This doesn't even require calculus but more common sense. Every second the height changes by $0.4$ centimetres, while the cross-section area is fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$V = \pi\cdot r^2\cdot h = \pi\cdot 5^2\cdot h = 25\pi h$. So: $\dfrac{dV}{dt} = 25\pi \dfrac{dh}{dt} = 25\pi 0.4 = 10\pi \approx 31.4 cm^3/s$

Comment: Thank you so much, you made my day. I'll finally be able to finish this assignment. It was so easy now that I think about, I feel kind of stupid but thanks again. I would vote up if I could.